# Jailbroken iPhone & App Store submission

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, jailbreak

One of my friends(who is a newbie iPhone developer) is having a jailbroken iPhone 3GS. He is developing an app which he plans to submit to the App Store. He is simply using it as a test phone and this is his first app.

1. Is there any problem in using the
   jailbroken iPhone to **test** the
   app which he will be submitting to
   App Store ?
2. Is there any drawbacks in using a
       jailbroken iPhone for iPhone
       Development and ultimately App Store
       Submission ?

*He is not planning to submit it to Cydia or any other repositories.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no problem with testing an app on a jailbroken iPhone. (There is no way for Apple to know, and even if there was, what would be the point of doing that?)
2. Jailbroken iPhones do not always exhibit the expected iPhone behaviour, as jailbreaking breaks stuff on lower OS levels to allow for unsigned apps to execute. In my experience, unexpected bugs tend to crop up once in a while. Best if your friend tests on an regular device prior to submission.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since he is a newbie he will not be using any advanced iPhone programming techniques. But can he able to test notifications like **Push/Local notifications** on the Jailbroken iPhones in the future ?

Comment: Sure. All apps and features should work as intended (unless the jailbreaking utility states otherwise).